# How can I get a photo from an android an put it in an Image control in Xamarin forms?

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, android-camera

I'm developing an app for Android in Xamarin forms.

I want to get an Image from an Android device an put into an image control.

For example, in my phone's gallery, there is an image called "image1.jpg" I wanna know How can I get this image an set to the image-control source.

I dont want to get an image from my Resources(drawable)

My code is:

Image_control.Source = ImageSource.FromFile(image1.jpg);

Comment: use the Media Plugin to allow a user to select an image and get its' path

Answer (score 1):

As Jason said , you can install ***[MediaPlugin](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/MediaPlugin)*** to realize it .

```
  pickPhoto.Clicked += async (sender, args) =>
  {
    if (!CrossMedia.Current.IsPickPhotoSupported)
    {
      DisplayAlert("Photos Not Supported", ":( Permission not granted to photos.", "OK");
      return;
    }
     var file = await Plugin.Media.CrossMedia.Current.PickPhotoAsync(new Plugin.Media.Abstractions.PickMediaOptions
                  {
                      PhotoSize =  Plugin.Media.Abstractions.PhotoSize.Medium,

                  });


    if (file == null)
      return;

    image.Source = ImageSource.FromStream(() =>
    {
      var stream = file.GetStream();
      file.Dispose();
      return stream;
    });
  };
```

Not forgetting to add permission in Android :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Last need to init Plugin in Activity and add permission callback method :

```
CrossCurrentActivity.Current.Init(this, bundle);

public override void OnRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, string[] permissions, Android.Content.PM.Permission[] grantResults)
{
    PermissionsImplementation.Current.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
}
```